# Which Unix is considered the vanilla Unix and which Unix's are just Unix rather than Unix-like?

Tags: sco

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11983/what-exactly-is-posix)
>   [What is Unix now?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14867/what-is-unix-now)

Are they only the Unix’s developed by Bell Labs or do the SCO ones count too? Are there others?

Comment: Also, check out [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55350/where-is-the-core-of-unix) question.

Answer (score 3):

UNIX (POSIX) is a set of "guidelines" which must be followed by an operating system (and it's parts) for it to be considered a "UNIX".

So asking which is the UNIX OS that the others are based on or which was the first doesn't really mean anything. Sure there was an operating system which was the first to be coined a UNIX -- but really, what you're talking about it the guidelines it follows.

Comment: So there is no current vanilla Unix OS at all?

Comment: @5ives, no because something like that doesn't exist. All operating systems which have the "UNIX" label follow the same standards and rules that have been defined by the organization which owns the UNIX label.

Comment: @5ives think of it like this. You can have hardcover and paperback books. These two things are defined traits that several books can have. You can't say that there is a hardcover book defined as the "vanilla" hardcover book.

Comment: Ok; is there a Unix that has a direct line to the original Unix rather than being some kind of branch? Which is the most current Unix by the original developers? Which Unix (not Unix-like) is the most popular? Sorry if I'm being stubborn.

Comment: @5ives I'm not sure about a UNIX which is still available today which is a descendant of the first OS to have the UNIX branding. I'm sure there is one...maybe someone else can pipe up on that. In terms of popularity, for consumers, I'd say Mac OSX is the UNIX with the largest user base.

Comment: What about the most popular CLI Unix?

Comment: @5ives FreeBSD is not Unix but is a direct descendant of the original ATT Unix and once contained original ATT Unix code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebsd

Comment: @Rob So is it more appropriate to call systems that have the original AT&T Unix code portions Unix-based, or Unix-like (although does that necessarily have to be true...), or just Unix (your comment indicates no)? Because I've seen FreeBSD referred to as all 3 on the web.

Comment: @Abdul I don't know and I don't think anyone cares. I would lean toward Unix based if I had to cause it had Unix in its code. Linux was Unix like because it copied Unix though it has strayed from that.

Answer (score 2):

[Unix is a trademarked name](http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix.html) and [there is only one specification for Unix](http://www.unix.org/version3/online.html). To be called a Unix system, you must apply for and be certified to use that name.

Comment: So which OS's have been certified?

Comment: From wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix):  Systems licensed to use the UNIX trademark include AIX, HP-UX, IRIX, Solaris, Tru64 (formerly "Digital UNIX"), A/UX, Mac OS X,[28][29] and a part of z/OS.

Comment: http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about code base lineage and not standards, current OSes directly descending from the original Bell Labs / AT&T Unix releases are AIX, HP-UX, Oracle Solaris & OpenSolaris derivatives all coming from System V release 4 and (Open/Free/Net)BSD and derivatives from the much earlier Unix version 6.

While Mac OS X has some BSD code, its core is not a descendant of the Unix kernel code.

Comment: I'm wondering, if OS X is BSD based, and BSD had code from one of the original AT&T releases, how can you tell OS X's core isn't descendant from the Unix kernel code, when it isn't fully open source?

Answer (score 1):

The history and timeline of UNIX is nicely presented [here](http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/history_timeline.html) and shown pictorially [here](http://www.unix.org/images/chronology_big.gif).

As noted, there is a [single UNIX specification](http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/single_unix_specification.html) that defines "Unix" to which all products must conform to be officially compliant and branded.  The various vendor brands can be found [here](http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/).